# Подскажите пожалуйста как проверить объект (newsClone) на null, не создавая новых переменных. newsClone используется дальше в коде, не хочу засорять

Tags: typescript

[image: img]

```
class News {
  draw(data: string[]) {
    const news =
      data.length >= 10 ? data.filter((_item, idx) => idx < 10) : data;

    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    const newsItemTemp = document.querySelector(
      '#newsItemTemp'
    ) as HTMLTemplateElement;

    news.forEach((item, idx) => {
      const newsClone = newsItemTemp.content.cloneNode(true) as Element;

      if (idx % 2) {
        if (newsClone) {
          **newsClone.querySelector('.news__item').classList.add('alt');**
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Например так: `newsClone?.querySelector`. [Доки](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: Если if (newClone) оставить, то делать `newsClone?.` нет смысла и поэтому далее можно делать так `newsClone.querySelector('.news__item')?.classList.add('alt')`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin ни то ни другое к сожалению не работает. Eslint все равно пишет Object is possibly 'null'

Comment: @NaN-Simon Можно поробовать `newsClone!.querySelector`. [Доки](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

Comment: @NaN-Simon, какой именно объект _is possibly 'null'_?

Comment: @Grundy newsClone, подчеркивает eslint.(дословно Object is possibly 'null'.ts) Ломать strict я не могу, пока единственное решение нашел это плодить переменные и каждый раз делать проверку на null(идет сплошное обращение к newsClone). Но получается какая-то порнография:(

Comment: добавь скриншот, где ошибка подчеркивается

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Comment: обрати внимание, что проблема не в newsClone, а в `newsClone.querySelector('.news__item')` - который действительно может быть null. Код из комментария  Alexander Chernin решает эту проблему.

Comment: Действительно, я не убрал if, поэтому eslint ругался, а я не заметил свою ошибку. Спасибо)